# How to Get Keys & Values of Dictionary inside an Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

Query (SQLite) result will be saved in a dictionary which will be saved in an Array

```
string sql = "select * from account";
SqliteConnection m_dbConnection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source = database.sqlite");
m_dbConnection.Open();
SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


// This is the array
List<Dictionary<string, string>>  array = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

while (reader.Read())
{

    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int a = 0; a< reader.FieldCount; a++)
    {

        if (!reader.IsDBNull(a))
        {
            string key = reader.GetName(a);
            string value = reader.GetString(a).ToString();


            dictionary.Add(key, value);
            //Dictionary will be saved in the array
            array.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>(dictionary));
        }
    }       
}
```

Now I try to print out the key and value of every dictionary in the Array but it only prints out the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i ++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("array(" + i + ") Key=" + array[i].SelectMany(x=> x.Key) + "Value = " + array[i].SelectMany(x => x.Value)+ "\n \n");
}
```

> array(x) Key=System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String],System.Char]Value = System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String],System.Char]

Instead of the value and the key itself. Why?

Or do you have any suggestion how I can save the Dictionary as an Array without using List? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code calls the default `ToString()` of the collection instead of what you are expecting. Create a string with the values using [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string.Join(",",array[i].Select(x=> x.Key))
```

Also use `Select` instead of `SelectMany` as you have a single value in each item and not a nested collection.

*And as a side note - `array` is a bad name for a parameters, let alone that it is a list and not an array.*

**However** I think a list of dictionaries is not what you are looking for. You would probably want to create a custom type with properties where each column retrieved for a row in the database is a property.

Comment: Hi Gilad, thank you for your answer. Just tried it and it worked!

Yes previously I used that way where I create a custom class named Account which has properties like the table in the database, (name, id, address, etc.)

But I was suggested to it this way where I put the query result into the dictionary where key is the column name and value is the row. So everytime the database table changed I don't have to change the custom class.

What do you think about that idea?

Comment: @jeansusgodney - I think that a class is better. The DB schema shouldn't change much and if it does then a different kind of schema should be considered. In general this is the conflict between a relational DB and an OOP language. I recommend looking into ORMs like EF/Nhibernate/... and use one. Will make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your code you can do this:

```
Debug.WriteLine("array(" + i + ") Key=" + array[i].Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault() + "Value = " + array[i].Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault() + "\n \n");
```

I just don't undestand why you're creating a list of dictionary if you only have one key/pair per dictionary

Comment: The dictionary share the same key (e.g. name or id)  because the key is the name of the column itself.

Comment: no problem... I just gave an extra option to have what you want using only linq ;)